# Custom G-Suite User Attributes

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm wondering if it's possible and how we would set custom attributes with a default value in G-Suite which automatically gets populated when we set-up a new user?

I can batch update in GAM tool, however this is extra steps which I want to try and automate.

gam update user [EMAIL HERE] PF_Talent_Management.TMIdpId_Live peoplefluent-prod

N/A

Answer (score 1):

with GAM you can create the User and it's costum attribute too in the same time :

```
gam create user <email address>
 [schemaname.fieldname <fieldvalue>]
 [schemaname.multivaluefieldname multivalued <fieldvalue>]
```

check this URL for more infos:
https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GAM3DirectoryCommands#setting-custom-user-schema-fields-at-create-or-update